# PyTorch DQN code does not solve OpenAI CartPole

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

The code is from DeepLizard tutorials ; it shows that the agent can only achieve 100 episode moving average of 80-120 seconds before resetting for the next episode. OpenAI gym considers 195 average is solving it.

the agent takes in an image frame instead of the observation space of 4.

what weakness is happening that I am not able to discover?

```
import gym
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import count
from PIL import Image
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.transforms as T    

is_ipython = 'inline' in matplotlib.get_backend()
if is_ipython: from IPython import display

batch_size = 256
gamma = 0.999
eps_start = 1
eps_end = 0.01
eps_decay = 0.001
target_update = 10
memory_size = 50000
lr = 0.001
num_episodes = 1000


class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, img_height, img_width):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=img_height*img_width*3, out_features=24)   
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=24, out_features=32)
        self.out = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=2)

    def forward(self, t):
        t = t.flatten(start_dim=1)
        t = F.relu(self.fc1(t))
        t = F.relu(self.fc2(t))
        t = self.out(t)
        return t   

    
Experience = namedtuple(
    'Experience',
    ('state', 'action', 'next_state', 'reward')
)

class ReplayMemory():
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.memory = []
        self.push_count = 0

    def push(self, experience):
        if len(self.memory) < self.capacity:
            self.memory.append(experience)
        else:
            self.memory[self.push_count % self.capacity] = experience
        self.push_count += 1

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

    def can_provide_sample(self, batch_size):
        return len(self.memory) >= batch_size   


class EpsilonGreedyStrategy():
    def __init__(self, start, end, decay):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.decay = decay

    def get_exploration_rate(self, current_step):
        return self.end + (self.start - self.end) * \
            math.exp(-1. * current_step * self.decay)

class Agent():
    def __init__(self, strategy, num_actions, device):
        self.current_step = 0
        self.strategy = strategy
        self.num_actions = num_actions
        self.device = device
    
    def select_action(self, state, policy_net):
        rate = self.strategy.get_exploration_rate(self.current_step)
        self.current_step += 1

        if rate > random.random():
            action = random.randrange(self.num_actions)
            return torch.tensor([action]).to(self.device) # explore      
        else:
            with torch.no_grad():
                return policy_net(state).argmax(dim=1).to(self.device) # exploit


class CartPoleEnvManager():
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device
        self.env = gym.make('CartPole-v0').unwrapped
        self.env.reset()
        self.current_screen = None
        self.done = False

    def reset(self):
        self.env.reset()
        self.current_screen = None
            
    def close(self):
        self.env.close()
        
    def render(self, mode='human'):
        return self.env.render(mode)
    
    def num_actions_available(self):
        return self.env.action_space.n
    
    def take_action(self, action):        
        _, reward, self.done, _ = self.env.step(action.item())
        return torch.tensor([reward], device=self.device)

    def just_starting(self):
        return self.current_screen is None

    def get_state(self):
        if self.just_starting() or self.done:
            self.current_screen = self.get_processed_screen()
            black_screen = torch.zeros_like(self.current_screen)
            return black_screen
        else:
            s1 = self.current_screen
            s2 = self.get_processed_screen()
            self.current_screen = s2
            return s2 - s1

    def get_screen_height(self):
        screen = self.get_processed_screen()
        return screen.shape[2]
        
    def get_screen_width(self):
        screen = self.get_processed_screen()
        return screen.shape[3]

    def get_processed_screen(self):
        screen = self.render('rgb_array').transpose((2, 0, 1)) # PyTorch expects CHW
        screen = self.crop_screen(screen)
        return self.transform_screen_data(screen)

    def crop_screen(self, screen):
        screen_height = screen.shape[1]
        
        # Strip off top and bottom
        top = int(screen_height * 0.4)
        bottom = int(screen_height * 0.8)
        screen = screen[:, top:bottom, :]
        return screen

    def transform_screen_data(self, screen):       
        # Convert to float, rescale, convert to tensor
        screen = np.ascontiguousarray(screen, dtype=np.float32) / 255
        screen = torch.from_numpy(screen)
        
        # Use torchvision package to compose image transforms
        resize = T.Compose([
            T.ToPILImage()
            ,T.Resize((40,90))
            ,T.ToTensor()
        ])
        
        return resize(screen).unsqueeze(0).to(self.device) # add a batch dimension (BCHW)

class QValues():
    device = torch.device("cpu")

    @staticmethod
    def get_current(policy_net, states, actions):
        return policy_net(states).gather(dim=1, index=actions.unsqueeze(-1))

    @staticmethod        
    def get_next(target_net, next_states):                
        final_state_locations = next_states.flatten(start_dim=1) \
            .max(dim=1)[0].eq(0).type(torch.bool)
        non_final_state_locations = (final_state_locations == False)
        non_final_states = next_states[non_final_state_locations]
        batch_size = next_states.shape[0]
        values = torch.zeros(batch_size).to(QValues.device)
        values[non_final_state_locations] = target_net(non_final_states).max(dim=1)[0].detach()
        return values


def plot(values, moving_avg_period):
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.clf()        
    plt.title('Training...')
    plt.xlabel('Episode')
    plt.ylabel('Duration')
    plt.plot(values)

    moving_avg = get_moving_average(moving_avg_period, values)
    plt.plot(moving_avg)    
    plt.pause(0.001)
    print("Episode", len(values), "\n", \
        moving_avg_period, "episode moving avg:", moving_avg[-1])
    if is_ipython: display.clear_output(wait=True)


def get_moving_average(period, values):
    values = torch.tensor(values, dtype=torch.float)
    if len(values) >= period:
        moving_avg = values.unfold(dimension=0, size=period, step=1) \
            .mean(dim=1).flatten(start_dim=0)
        moving_avg = torch.cat((torch.zeros(period-1), moving_avg))
        return moving_avg.numpy()
    else:
        moving_avg = torch.zeros(len(values))
        return moving_avg.numpy()


def extract_tensors(experiences):
    # Convert batch of Experiences to Experience of batches
    batch = Experience(*zip(*experiences))

    t1 = torch.cat(batch.state)
    t2 = torch.cat(batch.action)
    t3 = torch.cat(batch.reward)
    t4 = torch.cat(batch.next_state)

    return (t1,t2,t3,t4)

device = torch.device("cpu")
em = CartPoleEnvManager(device)
strategy = EpsilonGreedyStrategy(eps_start, eps_end, eps_decay)
agent = Agent(strategy, em.num_actions_available(), device)
memory = ReplayMemory(memory_size)

policy_net = DQN(em.get_screen_height(), em.get_screen_width()).to(device)
target_net = DQN(em.get_screen_height(), em.get_screen_width()).to(device)
target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net.state_dict())
target_net.eval()
optimizer = optim.Adam(params=policy_net.parameters(), lr=lr)

episode_durations = []
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    em.reset()
    state = em.get_state()

    for timestep in count():
        action = agent.select_action(state, policy_net)
        reward = em.take_action(action)
        next_state = em.get_state()
        memory.push(Experience(state, action, next_state, reward))
        state = next_state

        if memory.can_provide_sample(batch_size):
            experiences = memory.sample(batch_size)
            states, actions, rewards, next_states = extract_tensors(experiences)
            
            current_q_values = QValues.get_current(policy_net, states, actions)
            next_q_values = QValues.get_next(target_net, next_states)
            target_q_values = (next_q_values * gamma) + rewards

            loss = F.mse_loss(current_q_values, target_q_values.unsqueeze(1))
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        if em.done:
            episode_durations.append(timestep)
            plot(episode_durations, 100)
            break

    if episode % target_update == 0:
        target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net.state_dict())

em.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating your target_net after N of EPISODES, this slows down the progress significantly and can hinder reaching the optimal policy. Go on and try to update your target_net after N timesteps. Good luck!

Comment: I changed the `if episode % target_update == 0:` to `if timestep % target_update == 0:` and moved the if statement into the for timestep loop and I didn't see any improvements. Could you elaborate on what you meant? Thanks!

Comment: Everything else seems to be ok with your code. Try lr = 0.003 and increase the size of your neural network (add another layer, increase the number of nodes)

Comment: Please set your device to GPU not CPU (use cuda) and also set **policy_net.train()** explicitly

Comment: CUDA doesn't work with my GPU as it's an intel driver. I'm going to try a GPU cluster this week. How would I set the policy_net.train() exactly and where should I put it? What does setting that explicitly actually do?

Comment: 1. From my experience, 100 episodes on CPU is completely different than on GPU, CPU will not solve problems, I don't know why that happens. I think once you start using GPU you will solve the CartPole.  2. You can set **policy_net.train()** anywhere before the **for loop**, but I would do it right after/before you wrote **target_net.eval()**.

Comment: 2. Why is policy_net.train() so important? 
3. I am actually using learning rate decay provided by pytorch for example `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=100, gamma=0.9)` by lr=0.01. Do you think that is better than using a constant lr?

Comment: Another question: do you know a way to not have a rendering come up so that the game runs faster?

Comment: If you are using pixels for state values than you can't do that, sorry. Only way to this is to use observation values that come from within the environment instead of raw pixels.

Comment: Do you know how I can update the code to do that? I've been trying to do it but I am not getting it to work. Or do you suggest just using the current setup? The problem with the current setup is that it never reaches optimal policy and I would assume that has to do partially with that it's probably difficult to guess what to do based on two images.

Comment: 1. Actually, if you could reach 120 timesteps per episode level then just increasing the neural network should help to boost the performance. 2. The built-in state space values are returned by **env.step(action.item())** in **def take_action(self, action)**, you can use those.

Comment: 1. How can I achieve 120 timesteps per episode?
2. Yea I tried to use env.step(action.item()) but I keep getting errors. 
3. Which layers do you recommend? Just continue to use fully connected?

Comment: You already said that your agent achieves 80-120 timesteps per episode result (you said seconds but I guess you meant timesteps). To increase your network just add more nodes. No need for Conv-nets for this task.